# jQuery 'trigger('click')` not working on opera if the element is not displayed

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari, opera

I have some element which click on it event triggers click on `<input style="display:none" type="file"/>` element.
this element is hidden (`display:none`).
On this browser: Chrome, IE, FireFox it is working (the trigger executes) but on Opera and Safari it doesn't. Is there any special thing I need to do for the problematic browsers (Opera and Safari)? Is there any walk around?

Many thanks!

here is the code of the event

```
$('#add_cv').click(function(){
   $('#add_cv_input').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have written?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I found this workaround, I have set the element's css to:

```
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top:0;
```

it is working on every browser above. 
I will be more than glad to hear any other solutions.

Comment: The element will just be transparent, not clickable and (eventually) on the top of the page. Any links or buttons below it can't be clicked.

Comment: I would just make the `top` and `left` values negative and then it shouldn't cover anything.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following as an alternative to `display: none`:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: -9999px;
```